Looking for a substance to create sparks when hit
In my country there is a folk dance where the men wear shoes with metallic plates on the inside of the ankles that make a strong sound when touched.
I am also a dancer and looking for a non-toxic substance that can be applied on the metallic plates and can create sparks when the plates are hit. I want the dance to be more spectacular.
The sparks should not burn the dancer's costume or the floor and the substance should be enough for a few minutes of dancing.
I am thinking that the substance should be something that could be found commercially (ideally, it could be transported over airplane, but I am open to anything). Also, could it generate sparks of different colors?
Is there such a substance?

Maybe too trivial, but https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flint; there are commercially available shoe flint pads.

Mischmetal, an alloy of various lanthanides, is readily available, and sold for use as a fire-starter, e.g., lighter and torch sparker "flints". Amazon, for example, even has such flints with straps to hold them to shoes. According to United Nuclear, their mischmetal rods have no shipping restrictions.
That said, there might be some issues.

The sparkers work well on a hard surface, such as concrete or stone. They would not work on a wooden stage.
The sparks can ignite combustible materials. Use on an outdoor concrete stage, surrounded by dry grass, might be hazardous.
The color of the sparks are a bright white. One could experiment painting or plating the rods with something to change the color, such as copper (green), or salt (yellow, from sodium), though I doubt much color would be added. You might have seen spinning sheet-metal sparkler toys, which used mischmetal for sparks, and colored cellophane filters for color. You could place colored cellophane on stage at foot-level...


Thank you. It is a nice idea, but it seems they require quite an amount of friction to produce sparks. In this dance, the metal pads are hit when the dancer hits his inner sides of the ankles, so it is mostly impact, not friction. Also, we perform only on wooden stages.

@CristianM On wood? Then this is all a no go. You can't make sparks and even if you somehow did, it could be dangerous.

@Mithoron, oh, he could make sparks (err... maybe an explosion), even on impact with wood -- nitrogen triiodide. But it would be dangerous!
